# Server side rendering with React-rails and Algolia

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails, algolia

I'm trying to prerender my react app server side but I came accross a problem:
as soon as I `require('algoliasearch')` I get `ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined`

I tried to use [faux-jax](https://github.com/algolia/faux-jax) to mock `XMLHttpRequest` but then I get `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` And after all I don't think that's the way to go.

Any idea on this problem?

Answer (score 1):

are you using nodejs? If so which version?

When using nodejs 0.12 I cannot reproduce your issue:

```
> node -v
0.12.13
> npm install algoliasearch
node
> var algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
undefined
> algoliasearch
{ [Function: algoliasearch] version: '3.4.0', ua: 'Algolia for Node.js 3.4.0' }
```

Comment: Hum, I had `0.10` but updated to `0.12` and still have the error. It seems that the error is related to React-Rails or ExecJS and not node itself. As soon as I remove `require('algoliasearch')` from my react app, the rendering works...
Could it be related to `algoliasearch` dependencies?

Comment: Can you do exactly the lines I did and let me know if it works?

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that I did the line you did and it worked.

Comment: The weird thing is that at no point you should get "XMLHttpRequest is not defined". This code is only loaded when used with browserify or webpack.

I do not know what is execJS but yes it seems more related to execJS than to node or react.

Comment: There seems to be incompatibilities between react rails and browserify https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/129

Comment: It could be related to the package.json of the algoliasearch module but I really do not know what is hapening. It seems there's someone trying to load `src/browser/builds/algoliasearch.js` server side while it should just load index.js